# dar formato a texto de dataset PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

Estimados estoy realizando un bot de telegram el cual raspa un sitio de sismos, necesito que los datos en telegram salgan formateados, que los cabeceras esten con los datos que corresponde, les dejo la funciones.

```
def sismo_scraping():
    e = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sismologia.cl/ultimos_sismos.html").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(e, 'html.parser')

    # Obt    enemos la tabla

    tabla_sismos = soup.find_all('table')[0]

    # Obtenemos todas las filas
    rows = tabla_sismos.find_all("tr")

    output_rows = []
    for row in rows:
        # obtenemos todas las columns
        cells = row.find_all("td")
        output_row = []
        if len(cells) > 0:
            for cell in cells:
                output_row.append(cell.text)
            output_rows.append(output_row)

    dataset = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)

    dataset.columns = [
        "Fecha Local",
        "Fecha UTC",
        "Latitud",
        "Longitud",
        "Profundidad [Km]",
        "Magnitud",
        "Referencia Geográfica",
    ]
    dataset[["Latitud", "Longitud"]] = dataset[["Latitud", "Longitud"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    
    dataset_filter = dataset[
            (-21.655 <= dataset["Latitud"])
            & (dataset["Latitud"] <= -19.370)
            & (-72.316 <= dataset["Longitud"])
            & (dataset["Longitud"] <= -68.426)
            ]
    
    row_1 = dataset_filter.head(1).to_string(index=False)
    
    resultado = row_1
    
    return resultado



def report():
    btc_price = f'{sismo_scraping()}'
    bot_send_text(btc_price)
```

los datos en telegram me aparecen de la siguiente forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que se vea así

Fecha local : fecha local

Fecha UTC : fecha UTC

Latitud: latitud

Longitud: longitud

Profundidad: profundidad

Magnitud: magnitud

Referencia geografica: referencia geografica

Comment: Da un ejemplo de como quieres que se ven los datos, por favor. Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir el ejemplo.

Comment: Editado, gracias por la acotación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El formato que quieres se puede construir así:

Columna + ":" + el primer valor de la columna + un salto de línea.

En tu código reemplaza estas líneas:

```
row_1 = dataset_filter.head(1).to_string(index=False)  
resultado = row_1    
return resultado
```

Por estas:

```
string=""
for column in dataset_filter.head(1).columns:
    string += column + ":" + str(dataset_filter[column].values[0]) + "\n"
    
return string
```

Listo.

En caso que el mensaje en Telegram se vea sin los saltos de línea, edita la pregunta y añade el código de la función `bot_send_text` a ver como lo andas haciendo.

Comment: funciono, muchas gracias